# Less cluttered if condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in Python and i was wondering if there is a more elegant way to express the following if condition:

```
a=0
b=0
c=0
d=0
e=0
f=0

if a!=0 and c!=0 and b==0 and d==0 and e==0 and f==0:
    print("Hello World!")
```

This is a simple toy example but in practice i have more than 6 letters and things get really cluttered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your condition basically breaks down into two pieces:

- some set of variables are all zero
- some set of variables are all nonzero

Then make two lists:

```
should_be_zero = [b, d, e, f]
should_be_nonzero = [a, c]
```

You can then re-express your condition as:

```
all(i == 0 for i in should_be_zero) and all(i != 0 for i in should_be_nonzero)
```

As noted in the comments, since we're talking about integers being zero/non-zero, the above is equivalent to

```
not any(should_be_zero) and all(should_be_nonzero)
```

Comment: `not any(should_be_zero) and all(should_be_nonzero)`?

Comment: @StephenRauch Good point. Though perhaps leaving the condition is illustrative in case the OP's conditions are actually more involved.

Comment: Add them both, he was asking for less cluttered?

Comment: @hoyland i am not sure why some people did not like my question but thank you for your helpful answer, it works great!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `all` and `any`.

```
if all((a, c)) and not any((b, d, e, f)):
    print("Hello World!")
```

Given a list or numbers, `all(...)` returns `True` if they are all non-zero and `not any(...)` returns `True` is they are all zero.

Comment: This is also a great solution that generalizes easily, thank you.

Comment: Is there an equivalent to all() and any() when values are not 0/1?

Comment: Not really, this is due to the fact that `True == 1` and `False == 0`, if you want to compare to any other value, then hoyland's answer is the correct way to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could exploit the fact that 0 is falsy and 1 is truthy:

```
if a and c and not b and not d and not e and not f:
    print("Hello World!")
```